# collect multiple functions and apply all of them on a dataframe

Tags: python

I have several functions:

```
def func1
def func2
def func3
```

I want to apply all of them in a specific order on a Python dataframe. I could do something like this:

```
df = func1(df)
df = func2(df)
df = func3(df)
```

or like:

```
df = func3(func2(func1(df)))
```

Is there any more Pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: You can try function composition https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop:

```
for f in (func1, func2, func3):
     df = f(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

put them all in class and make sure they all return the class then chain them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]])
class foo():
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        self.df = df

    def __call__(self, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        return foo(df=df)

    def print(self):
        print("here we go")
        print (self.df)
        return self

    def func1(self):
        self.df=self.df.append([[2,3]])
        return self
    def func2(self):
        self.df=self.df.append([[3,4]])
        return self
    def func3(self):
        self.df=self.df.append([[4,5]])
        return self 


a = foo(df)
a.print().func1().print().func2().print().func3().print()
```